# Sources is always open when I inspect elements

Tags: reactjs, debugging, devtools

[image]

Does anybody know how to exist this ?
Every time I open the dev tools or try to inspect something, always the source is opened.
How I can exit it permanently, so when I inspect or open the dev tools the console shows ?
I am using brave browser.

Comment: Get rid of the breakpoints?  Or press the stop sign icon above "Pause on caught exceptions" to disable breakpoints altogether.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: I just want to get rid of all of this, so when I open the dev tools ill see console instead of source

Comment: Try right-clicking on the breakpoints and removing them all.  Dev tools will automatically open and pause on breakpoints.

Comment: yes and how i exit this mode because every time i do this and refresh it will open again

Comment: It shouldn't open if you don't have breakpoints or if you disable the breakpoints by clicking that right pointed arrow with the line through it.  That should disable all breakpoints entirely.

Comment: It just comes back, I don't know why this is happening, but I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

`Control + Shift + J` (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS) to jump straight into the Console panel.